# How to work DB::connection ('odbc')->table() with scope in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, connection, odbc

I connect through a database through odbc, it works correctly, but I have to work with several search criteria, and I see the need to do it through scope.

I can make queries using in the controller:

```
$busqueda_db= DB::connection('odbc')->table('tbl_taller')->select('cod_empresa','nombre_empresa','numero_orden','anio','fecha_liquidacion' , 'estado')->where('cod_empresa',1)->where('estado','activo')->get();
```

My idea is to call the functions that are in the model, something like this:

```
public function scopeEmpresa(){
    return $this->where('codigo_empresa',2)->get();
}
public function scopeStatus(){ 
    return $this->where('estado','activo')->get(); 
}
```

I appreciate your valuable help, I still can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Mrhn, thanks, it is exactly what I was looking for, but now I have a problem, I need to send from the controller a variable to the scope that is in the model, I have tried it like this, but it does not work.

```
$cod_empresa = $request->get('codigo_empresa');

Taller::empresa($cod_empresa)
->select('cod_empresa','nombre_empresa','numero_orden','anio','fecha_liquidacion' , 'estado')->get();
```

In the Model:

```
public function scopeEmpresa($codigo_empresa){
      return $this->where('cod_empresa',$codigo_empresa);
}
```

How can I do it, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it with this:   public function scopeEmpresa($builder, $codigo_empresa){
      return $builder->where('cod_empresa',$codigo_empresa);
}